# Error while saving a bitmap in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am displaying an image in my MFC application and I want to save it as bitmap.
Here is my code.

```
BITMAPFILEHEADER bh;
    ZeroMemory(&bh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    bh.bfType = 0x4d42; //bitmap 
    bh.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bh.bfSize = bh.bfOffBits + ((IM_WIDTH*IM_HEIGHT*2)*3);

    CFile file;
    if(file.Open("Image1.bmp", CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite))
    { 
        file.Write(&bh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
        file.Write(&(bmi.bmiHeader), sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
        file.Write(im_final, 3 * IM_WIDTH * IM_HEIGHT*2);
        file.Close();
    }
```

I am using the same BITMAPINFOHEADER which I used to display the image.
But the saved image is not correct. 
Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183391.aspx and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format . There should be certain additional information after `BITMAPINFOHEADER` before the actual pixel data; the exact form of this additional information depends on the bitmap format specified in `BITMAPINFOHEADER`. Also, each scanline should be padded to a 4-byte boundary. If `IM_WIDTH` is not a multiple of 4, then your size-of-data calculations are wrong. By the way, why are you multiplying by 2? `*3` is probably because you have 24bpp bitmap, but why an extra `*2`?

Comment: Extra 2 is because I am upscaling my image, so I have to doublt the height.
Thanks for the reply. I will look into the header info. My image width is a multiple of 4 so it is not an issue.

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton :)
The header information did it for me. I included info about RGBQUAD and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I am using now which works fine:

```
BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
    bmfh.bfType = 0x4d42;  /* "BM" */
    bmfh.bfSize = (sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + bmih.biSize + bmih.biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD) + bmih.biSizeImage);
    bmfh.bfReserved1 = 0;
    bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;
    bmfh.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + bmih.biSize + bmih.biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD);

CString file = m_filepath;
char* savefile = file.GetBuffer();

hFile = CreateFile(savefile,  GENERIC_WRITE,  0, (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, (HANDLE) NULL);    





if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
  {

      WriteFile(hFile, (char *) &bmfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), (LPDWORD) &err, NULL);
      WriteFile(hFile, (char *) &bmih, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), (LPDWORD) &err, NULL);
      WriteFile(hFile, (char *) &bmi.bmiColors, sizeof(bmi.bmiColors), (LPDWORD) &err, NULL);
      WriteFile(hFile, im_rgb, bmih.biSizeImage, (LPDWORD) &err, NULL);

    CloseHandle(hFile);
  }
```